# Case statement in oracle with true condition

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

How do I make this query work in ORACLE SQL. This is a where clause in my SQL query.

```
AND (CASE 
       WHEN ('THIS_PARAMETER_VALUE') IS NULL 
       THEN 1=1 
       ELSE TABLE.COLUMN_NAME = ('THIS_PARAMETER_VALUE') 
     END)
```

Comment: Please post DDL of the table, sample data and expect result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write it like this, supposing the parameter name is your_parameter:

```
table.column_name=nvl(your_parameter,table.column_name)
```

So, if your_parameter is NULL, then this gives table.column_name=table.column_name (i.e. like 1=1), otherwise it gives table.column_name=your_parameter

Comment: Although this generally works, it filters out rows where `column_name` is `NULL`.  The `or` version is better for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is most safely expressed as:

```
AND (:parameter IS NULL OR TABLE.COLUMN_NAME = :parameter)
```